# Calculate sum of events at given times using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe containing timestamps, order-IDs and events, looking like this:

```
 time    ID   event 
 -----   --   ----- 
 10:00   A    start 
 10:01   B    start 
 10:02   A    process
 10:03   A    finish 
 10:04   B    process 
 10:05   B    finish
```

Let's assume an order "keeps" its event status as long as it has no new event entry. How can I create columns giving me the current number of orders having a certain event? To clarifiy: At each row I want to calculate the number of orders having a certain event.

The calculated data should look like this:

```
 time    ID   event    num_start  num_process  num_finish
 -----   --   -----    ---------  -----------  ----------
 10:00   A    start    1          0            0          
 10:01   B    start    2          0            0
 10:02   A    process  1          1            0
 10:03   A    finish   1          0            1
 10:04   B    process  0          1            1
 10:05   B    finish   0          0            2
```

The calculation is like this:

```
line "10:00": There is one order with event "start" (A), zero otherwise
line "10:01": There are two orders with event "start" (A and B), zero otherwise
line "10:02": order A has a new event. Now there is one order with event "start" (B) 
              and one order with event "process" (A)
and so on
```

Comment: The logic is unclear to me, can you break down the calculation for a few examples?

Comment: On the `num_start` column, why the first line starts at 1 and the line 5 starts at 0 ?

Comment: because at the end all events have finished, so we don't have events with the event start or process anymore. That's my understanding of the problem

Comment: A is starting so num_start = 1 then B starts so num_start=2, then A goes into process, so num_start decrements and goes to 1 meanwhile num_process is incremented and goes to 1. That's the logic that I'm seeing

Comment: @tricky that's exactly what I meant. I updated the question to show what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is basically some math operations over the cumulative sum of the OneHotEncoding of the column 'event'.

```py
import pandas as pd

time = pd.date_range("10:00:00", periods=6, freq='1min')

ID = ["A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B"]
event = ['start', 'start', 'process', 'finish', 'process', 'finish']
df= pd.DataFrame(data=zip(ID, event), index=time, columns=['ID', 'event'])

ohe = pd.get_dummies(df['event']).astype(int)

num_finish = ohe['finish'].cumsum()
num_finish.name = 'num_finish'

num_process = (ohe['process'] - ohe['finish']).cumsum()
num_process.name = 'num_process'

num_starts = ohe['start'].cumsum() - num_process - num_finish
num_starts.name = 'num_starts'

pd.concat([df, num_starts, num_process, num_finish], axis=1)
```

Comment: That code works, thanks! I have two questions:
What do you mean by OneHotEncoding?
Do you know of a way without the subtraction of the other columns? In my real application, the number of different events is unknown before runtime.